What is the most Python3 efficient way to store 'large' data?
I am modelling energy 'blobs' as a row of data containing 9 variables. I have created up to a billion (rows of) 'blobs' so far but now need to save them in some form of data structure where I can manipulate the variables in each blob'.
I am very new (1 week into learning Python) and generating a billion randomised blobs took 52 minutes on my pc. If I start to save the blobs in a form that I can read and write, then I am concerned about efficiency, hence the question.
What is the most efficient way to save large amounts of data so that I can read and write to any variable for any 'blob'?
This is how I am generating my 'blobs' at the moment, eobs is the variable for number of 'blobs':
for num in range(eobs):
    num = num + 1
    ex = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
    totx = totx + ex
    atotx = atotx + abs(ex)
    ey = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
    toty = toty + ey
    atoty = atoty + abs(ey)
    ez = random.normalvariate(0, 1)
    totz = totz + ez
    evalu = (ez)
    totevalu = (totevalu + evalu)
    atotz = atotz + abs(ez)
    if ez < 0:
        ecol = "blue"
    else:
        ecol = "red"
    txt = f"Energy object No{num}  ex={ex:.2f} ey={ey:.2f} ez={ez:.2f} evalu={evalu:.6f} {ecol}"
    print(txt)

This works fine but I would like to read/write/modify, ex in 'blob' number 47 for example.
Thank you for reading this.

Read up on numpy/pandas. Those libraries will allow you to manipulate large amounts of data very efficiently. For example, my phone can generate 100m random numbers with np.random.random((10000,10000)) in less than one second.
